# Understanding "redundant" columns in C-Store DB (column-oriented)

Tags: database, column-oriented

Following the [paper](http://db.csail.mit.edu/projects/cstore/vldb.pdf) published on C-store, I did not understand the part

> Redundant storage of elements of a table in several overlapping projections in different orders, so that a query can be solved using the most advantageous projection

Firstly, I did not understand how is it derived as to which column(s) make up for "redundant" columns in the database table?

Second, in reference to the point above, my understanding is that these columns marked as "redundant" don't have to be stored in every projection that is created on the table. If a query requests for such a column, only one of the projections would be needed to answer the query. Am I correct?